# 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'activeSelf'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate a prefab using an if statement with an active self in the function. Now I want to check weather the transformed object is active or not. If I write .activeSelf behind my Transform tho, its giving me an error. Here is the part that gives me problems:

```
public Transform SpawnPointBlue, SpawnPointRed;
public GameObject Mercury;

    public void SpawnMercury()
    {
        if(SpawnPointBlue.activeSelf == true)
        {
            Instantiate(Mercury, SpawnPointBlue.position, SpawnPointBlue.rotation);
        }

        if(SpawnPointRed.activeSelf == true)
        {   
            Instantiate(Mercury, SpawnPointRed.position, SpawnPointRed.rotation);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`activeSelf` is a property of `GameObject`, not `Transform`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html

So, you'd do this:

```
    if(SpawnPointBlue.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
    {
        Instantiate(Mercury, SpawnPointBlue.position, SpawnPointBlue.rotation);
    }
```

However, note that `activeSelf` just indicates if that object is active based on its own local setting. It could still be inactive in the scene if, for instance, its parent object is inactive. I'd recommend using `activeInHierarchy` instead.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html

```
    if(SpawnPointBlue.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        Instantiate(Mercury, SpawnPointBlue.position, SpawnPointBlue.rotation);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are checking the transform component.
Try this instead.

```
public GameObject SpawnPointBlue, SpawnPointRed;
public GameObject Mercury;

    public void SpawnMercury()
    {
        if(SpawnPointBlue.activeSelf == true)
        {
            Instantiate(Mercury, SpawnPointBlue.transform.position, SpawnPointBlue.transform.rotation);
        }

        if(SpawnPointRed.activeSelf == true)
        {   
            Instantiate(Mercury, SpawnPointRed.transform.position, SpawnPointRed.transform.rotation);
        }
    }
```

If that doesn't work try this

```
  public GameObject SpawnPointBlue, SpawnPointRed;
public GameObject Mercury;

    public void SpawnMercury()
    {
        if(SpawnPointBlue.isActive)
        {
            Instantiate(Mercury, SpawnPointBlue.transform.position, SpawnPointBlue.transform.rotation);
        }

        if(SpawnPointRed.isActive)
        {   
            Instantiate(Mercury, SpawnPointRed.transform.position, SpawnPointRed.transform.rotation);
        }
    }
```